# MYSQL - How to extract value from nested json?

Tags: mysql

I have a column "info" that stores nested json string that looks like this:

`{"Text":"5","Elements":{"New\\Old\\Used\\Sold\\Blank":{"123456":{"id":"056"}}}}`

I need to extract id value from this json string.
I tried using JSON_EXTRACT function in my select statement like this:

`trim(both'"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(info, '$.Elements[0][0][0][0]')) AS id,`

and i tried:

`trim(both'"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(info, '$.[1][0][0][0][0]')) AS id,`

But i am getting null values in column.

I tried using several other combination of where i changed numbers within square brackets to accommodate for element position but i always get null values.

Any suggestion how to extract the id from this json?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: Provide 3-5 possible JSON values (which vary as much as possible) and desired output for each provided value.

Answer (score 0):

`Elements` isn't an array, you can't use array indexing to extract from it.

```
info->>"$.Elements.New\\Old\\Used\\Sold\\Blank\\.123456.id"
```

Don't use `trim()` to remove the surrounding quotes, use either `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(...))` or `->>`.

Comment: thank you for your response. I see what you are saying. 
The problem is that the column info will contain json string in each row and that json string will have dinamic elements. SO i cant use .123456.id because that number 123456 will different in next json string. So i was trying to access to id by selecting the count of element position. Any idea how to do that in sql?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible in MySQL. MySQL's JSON functions are extremely limited. You may be better off just getting the whole value and doing it in the client programming language.

Comment: Yeah :-( i can do it very easily in python but i was hoping i can get this out with mysql

Comment: *As far as I know, it's not possible in MySQL.* I think that this statement is not correct. There is no problem to gather all keys from JSON which matches `"id"` pattern, and extract the values which matches extracted paths.

Comment: @Akina - Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Slavisha84 Read my comment to your question, please...